# How can I count up the name of a Button with a Variable

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a battleship game in which the game field buttons all start with the letter `A` and then a number. Now I want to count up the numbers but still be able to do basic button functions like `BackgroundImage`.

What I'm doing now is just create a sting which adds the `A` with the number I receive from the function.

```cs
string btnr = "A";
btnr = btnr + Convert.ToString(nr);
```

```cs
string btnr = "A";
btnr = btnr + Convert.ToString(nr);
btnr.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"T:\E\_AUSTAUSCH\Com.Menu_OpenSurce\Battleship\Bilder\ACC_5_W.png");
```

This should change the Background image of the Button with the "nr" xx but I already get an error message saying:

> Error 3 "string" contains no definition for "BackgroundImage", and no
>   extension method "BackgroundImage" could be found that accepts a first
>   argument of type "string". (Is there no Using directive or assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: A string of itself doesn't have `BackgroundImage`. I take it you are using winForms. You want to change the background of the `Button` where the string is used.

Comment: In short, your btnr needs to be of type Button, in order to access it's properties and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, you can use [Controls.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8) to get a reference to the Button, no matter how deeply nested it is:

```
string btnName = "A" + nr.ToString();
Control ctl = this.Controls.Find(btnName, true).FirstOrDefault();
if (ctl != null && ctl is Button)
{
    Button btn = (Button)ctl;
    btn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"T:\E\_AUSTAUSCH\Com.Menu_OpenSurce\Battleship\Bilder\ACC_5_W.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the button name. But you need to reference to the button object. To do this, you can use the controls property to select the button by name:

Please note that this example assumes that the button exists and the control is of type Button. Update: also assumes that the buttons are inmediate childs of the form

```
var button = (Button)Controls[btnr];
button.BackgroundImage = 
    Image.FromFile(@"T:\E\_AUSTAUSCH\Com.Menu_OpenSurce\Battleship\Bilder\ACC_5_W.png");
```

Comment: This also assumes that the button is **directly** contained by the Form.  It won't be found if the control is inside a different container.